# Что означает термин "синхронизированная коллекция"?

Tags: c#, терминология

Пожалуйста, помогите мне понять, что значит синхронизированный массив (на примере `HashTable.Synchronized(ArrayList list)`). Если можно, один пример.

Comment: например это тебе гарантирует, что 2 потока не будут писать в одну ячейку

Answer (score -1):

[второй результат](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized.aspx) ответа google на запрос **Hashtable.Synchronized**